# Checkboxes to be checked after saving in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angularjs for my application.I am using multiple checkbox selection and storing it in database in the format [1,2,3,4,5].For example if the checkbox selected is 1 then i am storing the value as 1.If multiple are selected then 1,2,3, and so on.

Here is the html

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div data-ng-repeat="healthStatus in HealthStatuses">
        <input  id="chkCustomer_{{healthStatus.Value}}" value="
            {{healthStatus.Value}}" type="checkbox" 
            data-ng-checked="selection.indexOf(healthStatus.Value) > -1" 
            data-ng-click="toggleSelectionHealthStatus(healthStatus.Value)" />
        {{healthStatus.Name}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the controller.js

```
$scope.HealthStatuses = [{
    Name: 'Alzheimers',
    Value: 1,
    Selected: false
}, {
    Name: 'Arthritis',
    Value: 2,
    Selected: false
},{
    Name: 'Cancer',
    Value: 3,
    Selected: false
},{
    Name: 'Cellulitis',
    Value: 4,
    Selected: false
}];
```

Here is how i am pushing the selected checkboxes value

```
$scope.selectionHealthStatus=[];
$scope.toggleSelectionHealthStatus = function toggleSelection(Value) {
    var idx = $scope.selectionHealthStatus.indexOf(Value);
    if (idx > -1) {
        $scope.selectionHealthStatus.splice(idx, 1);
    } else {
        $scope.selectionHealthStatus.push(Value);
    }
};
```

Now while retrieving the data i want the checkboxes to be checked.But now it is not happening.

Here is how i am retrieving the data

```
userPageService.getHealthStatus().then((data) => {
    data = data.data;
    $scope.formData = data;
});
```

If i put console for $scope.formData this is what i get.

```
participantIllnessAndDisability:"[1, 2, 3, 4]"
```

Here participantIllnessAndDisability is one field with multiple checkboxes selected.Now what i want to do is after adding the data while viewing i want the selected checkboxes to be checked.I am getting the data from database in [1,2,3] format.The datatype for field participantIllnessAndDisability in database is String.

Comment: Seems like you have a closing `</label>` tag with an opening counterpart .

Answer (score 0):

At load of page, the function on ng-checked won’t get automatically called. Hence it won’t check the check box.

You could assign ng-model or ng expression to checked property and initialize it from controller on data load.

Comment: I gave ng-model instead of ng-checked but it is throwing error

Answer (score 0):

### Update:

Please try this.

```
userPageService.getHealthStatus().then((data) => {
                 data = data.data;
                 $scope.formData = data;
                 $scope.HealthStatuses.forEach((o) => o.Selected = JSON.parse(data.participantIllnessAndDisability).includes(o.Value));
        });
```

Comment: i added the line but still checkbox is not getting checked

Comment: @SachinHR `$scope.selectionHealthStatus` values should be the format which i have updated in my answer

Comment: Yeah you can see it in my question.I am using same format

Comment: But you are returning like `"[1, 2, 3, 4]"` not that format.

Comment: Do you mean from database?

Comment: Yes. If you returning it from database with selected option is true or false. Then  we don't need make any change. But if it won't from database. then you should update your array from returning values..

Comment: But for ng-repeat i am using same format as you have mentioned.I am not understanding where exactly you are telling.

Comment: Do i need to change anything in html?because now its not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163460/discussion-between-ramesh-rajendran-and-sachin-hr).

Comment: No You don't need to change anything in html. Just add that line there.

Comment: OOPS! Please change HealthStatuses instead of selectionHealthStatus in my code . Updated!

Comment: Please try it in chrome browser. please

Comment: yeah i am using chrome